# Redirect to a specific domain specified route

Tags: laravel, redirect, controller, routes

Consider the following route set up:

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'blog.adambalan.local'], function() {
    Route::get('login', 'BlogController@login');
    Route::get('blogs', 'BlogController@getBlogs');
    Route::post('postLogin', 'BlogController@postLogin');
});
```

Now consider the following, which is in the `postLogin`:

```
    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        Session::flash('success', "Welcome back Adam. Care to manage your blogs?");
        return redirect()->route('blogs');
    } else {
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['We could not log you in. Sorry.']);
    }
```

The issue is with: `return redirect()->route('blogs');`

The error is: `Route [blogs] not defined.` **Is there a specific thing I'm suppose to do? A specific way to call domain specific routes?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to name a route `'blogs'`. The `redirect()->route('blogs')` refers to a route name not a url/path.

For a url/path you can use `redirect()->to($url)` or just `redirect($url)`.

[Laravel - Routing - Named Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#named-routes)

Comment: Your answer makes no sense. As you can see I have a specific sub domain with a get route called blogs. I want to redirect to that route. But it apparently doesn't exist even though you can clearly see it does

Comment: You haven't named any of those routes.

Comment: Huh? Can you be more specific?

Comment: Yea you can read all about named routes in the Laravel Documentation. https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#named-routes